Jupyter Notebook in VS Code Not Showing Output Text Correctly (Displays Only Dashes)
I am facing an issue with Jupyter Notebook in the VS Code extension. Whenever I run a cell with a print() statement, the output panel shows only dashes (---) instead of the actual text output. However, when I copy the output from the notebook and paste it elsewhere (e.g., a text editor), the output appears correctly.
Screenshot
I expected the print() statements to display their output correctly in the Jupyter Notebook output panel in VS Code, such as:
x = 10
print(x)
print("Hello, world!")

Expected Output:
10
Hello, world!

What Happened Instead: 
 .
 --


Set the font size:
settings.json:
"notebook.output.fontSize": 0


Thank you so much for your suggestion! Setting "notebook.output.fontSize" to a readable value fixed the issue for me. I had it set to 0, which was causing the output to not display correctly. I changed it to 14, and now everything is working perfectly.

@Shadiq Rahman Glad to know your problem has been solved!

Try to use display() instead of print()

Thank you for your suggestion! I tried using 'display()' instead of 'print()', but it seems to show the same result as print().

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
